# Odometer set duration via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, odometer

I'm using odometer.js from http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/ . Is there a way to set the duration of odometer.js bia javascript (for example the odometer run from value 0 to 47 that takes 10 second to finish)? I found this question https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/issues/91 and someone said that I need to change at 2 place (one of them is css and for me, the css one working). css one is like this :

```
.odometer.odometer-animating-up, .odometer.odometer-animating-down.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner {
      -webkit-transition-duration: 10s !important;
      -moz-transition-duration: 10s !important;
      -ms-transition-duration: 10s !important;
      -o-transition-duration: 10s !important;
       transition-duration: 10s !important;
}
```

}

But in my case, I want to set it using javascript, css. I tried using jquery like this :

```
$(element).css( 'transitionDelay' : duration+'s')
```

but not working. using the one from the docs didn't do anything too :

```
window.odometerOptions = {
    auto: false, // Don't automatically initialize everything with class 'odometer'
    selector: '.my-numbers', // Change the selector used to automatically find things to be animated
    format: '(,ddd).dd', // Change how digit groups are formatted, and how many digits are shown after the decimal point
    duration: 3000, // Change how long the javascript expects the CSS animation to take
    theme: 'car', // Specify the theme (if you have more than one theme css file on the page)
    animation: 'count' // Count is a simpler animation method which just increments the value,
                 // use it when you're looking for something more subtle.
};
```

any solution?

Update:

here's the fiddle. note that I still use css to control the duration

http://jsfiddle.net/mtamwd6w/

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a [Fiddle](http://www.jsbin.com) ?

Comment: here's the fiddle. note that I still use css to control the duration

http://jsfiddle.net/mtamwd6w/

Answer (score 1):

This is really old but for those who are looking for the answer, the method from the docs do work, but you have to set it *before* you load the CDN odometer.js file:

```
window.odometerOptions = {
    auto: false, // Don't automatically initialize everything with class 'odometer'
    selector: '.my-numbers', // Change the selector used to automatically find things to be animated
    format: '(,ddd).dd', // Change how digit groups are formatted, and how many digits are shown after the decimal point
    duration: 3000, // Change how long the javascript expects the CSS animation to take
    theme: 'car', // Specify the theme (if you have more than one theme css file on the page)
    animation: 'count' // Count is a simpler animation method which just increments the value,
                 // use it when you're looking for something more subtle.
};
```